# asp.net website - Can I tell if it has been precompiled?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a slightly odd situation.

One of my customers has an Asp.net (v2 of the framework) site on a dedicated server.

They have asked me to make some changes to the code as their developer has left. Apparently the latest version was on the server.

I downloaded that code, opened it in VS2010, converted it and it was fine. However, when I run the code I get compile time errors from the aspx pages, where they are calling for properties that dont exist in the code. (According to Find In Files, whole soluton, *.*)

So I did some digging. In the Bin file there is an assembly for the website. On the server this is over 300k. On my machine this is 180k.

I accept that this might simply be that the later compilers pack code better, but I'd be suprised if this shows as a 120k improvement.

So the only thing I can think of is that at some point he has made some changes and compiled the website, but didnt remove all the old .cs files first.

Is this possible, or can anyone suggest a different reason for me seeing the behaviour I am witnessing?

[Edit]

Ok, It isn't precompiled, so Im really struggling to understand whats going on now.

- I have all the code from the website.
- On the Server the code works.

However, as I have had my original question answered I'll close this, and no doubt come back tomorrow when I have dug a little deeper.

Thanks

Comment: Is the .dll date modified on the server the same (or similar enough) to the date of the last checkin? Maybe it's not the latest code, 120KB difference seems quite significant.

Comment: Are you sure you have all the code? ASP.Net is compiled into the DLLs, but these are then JIT'ed the first time a page is accessed. It is possible that the code version you have is different to that deployed on the server. One option would be to use ILDASM to inspect the IL in one of the server DLLs i.e. look for one of the missing properties and see if it's present in the Server DLL.

Comment: Shagglez - The developer left month ago and they are a one man band, with no source control. Ive got their PM looking for originals or developers notes. Anythign that can be used to clarify it.

Ive got an old machine here somewhere, with vs2005 on it, so I'll try that tomorrow and see what size the assembly is then when I compile it.

tomas - I have the code off the live server. (I have even tracertd the domain to make sure that there isnt an issue there!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to look at the `aspx` pages:

- if they have an `Assembly=` specified in the `@Page` directive,
- or the page is 1KB in size with some 'placeholder' text

Then it is pre-compiled.

In the first case it is 'partially compiled' (which amounts to 'updateable', i.e. you can change *some* stuff). In the latter case it is 'fully compiled'.

Also, and perhaps most notably, would be the absence of code files (*.vb, *.cs, etc.) - since, regardless of the mode of compilation (if compiled at all), they *will* be compiled into binaries. If the source files are all there in place, then chances are you have a non-compiled solution - or a really, really strange project setup.

Comment: +1. However, have seen many, many "really, really strange project setups" ;-)

Comment: It has neither of those options. So Im left scratching my head a bit!

It's late now, so I'll do some more digging tomorrow, thanks for clearing up the pre compiled issue though.

Answer (score 0):

There could be other explanations. One of them, for example, is that the previous developer used a version control software and didn't add all the files he/she used to it, and that's what you downloaded, i.e. some files are actually missing.

Comment: I got my code off the Live server. If it isnt precompiled somehow then Im sure I have all the code he uploaded, ta.

Answer (score -1):

Being in your place, I would inspect the assembly by some assembly browser, like ILSpy. Then you can see what's in there and if it's different from your code files.

Comment: This is an extremely long winded approach, and yet still flawed: if the OP has binaries for the site itself then they already possess the knowledge they're aiming to acquire.